# Retrieving list of interface object from database using ormLite

Tags: java, database, spring, orm, ormlite

I am trying to make a database with these models

**Report model**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "report")
public class Report {

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int id;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "client_name")
private String client;

@ForeignCollectionField(maxEagerLevel = 2, eager = true)
private Collection<Product> productList;
```

**Product model**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "product")
public abstract class Product implements Comparable<Product> {

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int id;

@DatabaseField(foreign = true)
private Report report;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "instance")
private String instance;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "product_type")
private String productType;
```

So I am able to successfully insert in the tables, 
but when trying out:

```
List<Report> reports = reportDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("client_name", clientName).query();
```

I get an exception

```
Could not create object for class model.product.Product
```

So it makes sense, because Product is abstract, but is there a way using the "Instance" attribute from Product interface which indicates what kind of implementation of product it is, to create the appropriate object while running the query?

Thank you